# BATCH move files to C:\Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to move sleep.exe and nircmd.exe to C:\Windows using move command in my batch file. The code goes like this

```
    move "%cd%\sleep.exe" "C:\Windows"
    move "%cd%\nircmd.exe" "C:\Windows"
```

When I do not use administrator privileges I get error:

```
    Access denied
```

But when I use administrator privileges I get error:

```
    System cannot find the path specified
```

EDIT:
I also tried:

```
     move "%cd%\sleep.exe" "C:\users\%username%\desktop"
```

And that worked, but as I said I want it to move to C:\Windows

Comment: Firstly, check what `%CD%` extracts to (simply `echo` it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know that administrator mode changes your current director (%cd%)
but thanks to @foxidrive i know that now gooled it and found the answer

```
    @setlocal enableextensions
    @cd /d "%~dp0"
```

Answer (score 1):

When using administrator it resets the working directory, and which is why it couldn't find the files.

The solution here sets the location of the files to the folder which contains the batch file.

```
for %%a in ("sleep.exe" "nircmd.exe") do move "%~dp0\%%~a" "C:\Windows"
```

Comment: what if the files are in %cd%\Components?